# Простое серверное приложение для работы с БД + вывод в HTML

Tags: java, mysql, веб-программирование, tomcat

Добрый день, есть такая задача - Нужно создать простое серверное приложение для вызова трех хранимых процедур из базы MySQL. И прикрутить к этому html страницу для отображения данных.

Базу данных я сделал, простенькую таблицу и три хранимые процедуры тоже. Создал Maven проект в idea, по примеру задерплоил Hello World приложение на сервер, выдал он мне что надо. Завязал даже сервлет на страничку JSP. Отдельно сделал другой проект maven и протестил подключение к MySQL с помощью JDBC такой программкой:

```
import com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Connection connection;

        try {
            Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Соединение с БД установлено!");
            }

            connection.close();

            if (connection.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Соединение с БД закрыто!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Не удалось загрузить класс драйвера!");
        }
    } 
}
```

Но беда в том, что я не могу понять, как мне связать базу данных с локальным сервером и прикрутить к этому всему HTML страницу с интерфейсом. Может я что то лишнее использую? Помогите разобраться с этой кашей, что мне не нужно, чего нехватает?
Может надо в класс MyServlet просто добавить соединение с БД и вызов процедур из неё? Кажется что я где то рядом, но всё ещё не получается.

Comment: можно использовать persistence.xml затем работать с JPA, а для работы с HTML можно использовать Servlet потом responce и request делать на JSP страничку, Или же можно использовать Rest сервис

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создавать один проект, в котором буде и сервер с базою даных и вебка.
При создании maven проекта можете использовать `maven-archetype-webapp`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как прописать зависимости?

Comment: @Hev там будет `pom.xml` - в нем и пропишете